# How to search for specific text output in VSCODE terminal, as in ctrl-f?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

This was working before until I installed it on a new machine.

Why doesn't ctrl-f work in the terminal?

EDIT: SOLUTION: I had this setting enabled, which I toggled to false:

`"terminal.integrated.sendKeybindingsToShell": true,`

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. What do you see when you [troubleshoot your keybindings](//github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues)? Please paste the relevant parts of what you see into a code block in your question post.